# Send Email using php code

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email. but my code is not working. Can you which step is missing?

Send Message

**Email.php**

```html
<?php

if($_REQUEST['name'] == '' || $_REQUEST['email'] == '' || $_REQUEST['message'] == ''):
  return "error";
endif;

if (filter_var($_REQUEST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):

  $to = 'sendmeyour_Query@yahoo.com';

      // prepare header
$header = 'From: '. $_REQUEST['name'] . ' <'. $_REQUEST['email'] .'>'. "\r\n";
$header .= 'Reply-To:  '. $_REQUEST['name'] . ' <'. $_REQUEST['email'] .'>'. "\r\n";

$header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$subject = "Email from KG Construction Website";

$message .= 'Name: ' . $_REQUEST['name'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\n";
$message .= 'Message: '. $_REQUEST['message'];

$mail = mail( $to, $url , $message, $header );

return $mail ? "success" : "error";
else:
  return "error";
endif;
?>
```

Please help me out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Does it fail, not send the email, throw an error?

Comment: this is the error
 Warning: mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: Do you have SMTP service running on local host listening on TCP port 25?

Comment: SMTP service is not running on my local host. when application is deployed on server is that required or not. how to run smtp service locally?